# Fixed time per questions in quiz modules

Tags: 7

I'm new to Drupal, and I'm developing a site in Drupal 6. It's an online exam related site. I want to add quiz questions that have their own time; each question will have its individual time, and the total time of the quiz will be the total sum of the single question's times.

Is this possible in Drupal 6 with one of the quiz modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quiz module allows you to have a time for the whole quiz: http://drupal.org/project/quiz

To do time it per question you might have to make your own solution or you might be able to use hook_nodeapi() and update the 'time limit' field in the  'quiz_node_properties' table with the total of each question: http://drupalcode.org/project/quiz.git/blob/refs/heads/6.x-4.x:/quiz.module but it would be far from an out of the box solution.

Comment: You are correct acouch. The Quiz module has a functionality that sets a time limit to the quiz and not to each and every questions. But i find your idea a good one and would like to contribute such a feature to Quiz module at the earliest.

Comment: I have implemented this in my site and its working good. I have put one CCK second fields for all question type so from second, i have put timer using hook in my template file and its working great.:)

Answer (score 2):

Made a similar functionality for their tasks.

https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz/issues/2940636