# How can I set time limit for each question in quiz module?

Tags: quiz

I have been searching for settings where I set time for each question in a quiz. For example setting 30 seconds for allowing answer to a question.

I wonder why this option is not available in quiz module? It's so important. I'm not able to find this option when creating a quiz.

Is there any additional module available for it?

Comment: Have a loot at [Fixed time per questions in quiz modules](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/21859/25879). Ofcourse it's for D6, you can implement similar for D7 too.

Answer (score 0):

[Searching google for 'drupal quiz timer'](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?q=drupal%20quiz%20timer) brings up an [issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/653302) from the module queue that is fixed, and points the reader to the [FAQ's](https://www.drupal.org/node/507090#12) for the module.

Apparently you need [UserPoints](http://drupal.org/project/userpoints) and [JQuery Countdown](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_countdown) modules enabled, then go to `admin/quiz/settings` to enable.

Comment: The above issue and FAQ allows setting quiz timer for whole quiz, but not for individual question. What I'm trying to figure out is setting time for each individual questions. Is it available in any contributed modules?

Comment: Oh, I see.  I don't know. You may have to write a custom module for it.